# Как switch вынести в отдельный файл?

Tags: php, switch, case

Можно ли `switch` вынести в отдельный файл, учитывая то, что он находится в другом `switch`? Просто в основном файле получается слишком много кода, хотелось бы его пораскидать по разным файлам. `include` не работает. Пример:

```js
<?php 

//Тут получение JSON файла 

switch ($data->type) { 
  //Если это уведомление для подтверждения адреса сервера... 
  case 'confirmation': 
    echo $confirmation_token; 
    break; 

  case 'message': 
  //switch ниже как раз и нужно вынести в отдельный файл, если использовать include, то не работает
    switch($message) {
       case 1: echo $q1; break;
       case 2: echo $q2; break;
       case 3: echo $q3; break;
     }
break; 
}
```

Comment: выносить надо не `switch`, а общую некую логику хотя бы, обернув в функцию.... например `function getLang()` или `function recalcDate()` ..... причем выносить не каждую функцию в свой файл, а по общим признакам.... `helpers`, `html`, `date` и пр

Comment: поясните вообще,  что значит не работает если вынести в `include`? ибо сам инклуд работает, и проблемы нет никакой при этом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том, чтобы вынести конструкцию `switch` в отдельный файл и включить ее в с помощью `include` нет никакой сложности. Проблема в том, что это в принципе плохой подход.

допустим ваш основной файл `index.php`:

```
$data = ['type' => 'message'];
$message = 2;

switch($data['type']){
    case 'confirmation':  echo $confirmation_token; break;
    case 'message':.
            include "./switch_messages.php";
            break;
}
```

и дополнительный файл `switch_messages.php` следующего вида:

```
<?php
    list($q1, $q2, $q3) = ['q1 value', 'q2 value', 'q3 value'];

    switch($message){
        case 1 : echo $q1; break;
        case 2 : echo $q2; break;
        case 3 : echo $q3; break;
    }
```

Вы, наверное, тут должны понимать, что последний `switch` можно представить в виде:

```
$data = [1 => $q1, 2 => $q2, 3 => $q3];
echo $data['message'];
```

и обойтись вообще без `switch`. Возможно, предварительно надо проверить наличие искомого ключа в массиве и т.п.

В комментариях, вам предлагается заменить `include` на вызов функции. Это куда более практичный и удобный способ и потребует не особо больше действий с вашей стороны. В таком случае код немного видоизменяется, но смысл остается тот же.

```
require_once("process_messages.php");

$data = ['type' => 'message'];
$message = 2;

switch($data['type']){
    case 'confirmation':  echo $confirmation_token; break;
    case 'message':.
            processMessage($message);
            break;
}
```

где `process_messages.php`:
witch_messages.php` следующего вида:

```
<?php

    function processMessage($message){
        list($q1, $q2, $q3) = ['q1 value', 'q2 value', 'q3 value'];

        switch($message){
            case 1 : echo $q1; break;
            case 2 : echo $q2; break;
            case 3 : echo $q3; break;
        }
    }
```

в таком виде (процедурное программирование) код более удобен для поддержки, чего не скажешь про вариант с чистым `include`, где конечный php-файл собирается из разных кусков.  Следующим этапом для вас должен стать переход от процедурного к объекто-ориентированному программированию, если это имеет смысл в данной задаче. ООП не панацея, но хорошее средство, использовать его везде где попало смысла тоже нет.

Answer (score 1):

Легко. Делаем файл например "json_processor.php"
В него запиливаем функцию а-ля:

```
function parse_json($data)
```

В тело функции все твои свичи. Затем вызываеш эту функцию. Вот и готово.

Comment: в каком месте вы не поняли, что автору не надо длинной портянки из switch?  Зачем ее из одного места переносить в другое?

Comment: @teran, как раз это и нужно. Сократить там ничего особо не получится, но разнести по файлам стоило бы, а то основной код сложночитаемым получается.

Comment: Можете поподробнее расписать про эту function? Именно как ее вызывать в основном файле? И как оформить в "json_processor.php"?

Comment: @So-so вам тут и предлагают весь длинный основной код запихать в отдельный файл в виде функции. Вам какая разница где эта длинная функция будет в одном файле или в другом? Вы хотели разделить его  на части, здесь пишут про другое.

Comment: @teran, а, тогда да. Я проверил запихав один свич в функцию и вызвав в основном свиче, ничего не заработало